# Usage of "interest"

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, passive-voice

Consider these sentences:

> 1) You have interested in reading
>
> 2) You are interested in reading.

In the above sentences, is there any difference between using perfect tense(have+past participle) and passive voice('be'verb+past participle).

Do these sentences have same meaning?

Comment: The difference is the first example isn't a valid English sentence (in *any* context, although it could feasibly occur as a clause in, say, *I am one of the students you have interested in reading*).

Answer (score 2):

The voice (active or passive) and the tense (present, perfect etc) are things that you can choose independently. You don't have to choose **either** passive **or** perfect: you can have active present, passive present, active perfect and passive perfect.

First, let's look at the present. When used in active voice, the verb **interest** requires an object:

> you interest **me**.

We can also use it in passive voice. First of all, the object of the active voice sentence becomes the subject of the passive voice sentence, **me** -> **I**.

For most verbs, we can specify the **agent** (the subject of an active voice sentence) using the preposition **by**, but for **interested** we use the preposition **in**.

> I am interested **in** you.

We can put both the active and the passive voice versions into the past, like this:

> you interest me -> you **have interested** me. - *active voice*.
>   I am interested in reading -> I **have been** interested in you... *passive voice*.

Note that, in the passive voice version, we put the **am** into past, **have been**. Note also that these sentences would feel better with a time clause like *since...* or *for a long time*.

Comparing these with your first sentence, it is easy to see that your first sentence lacks an object **me**:

> You have interested **me** in reading

Comment: I found in dictionary "interested" as an adjective . It wasn't the case for many past particle of other verbs. In my example one can say "I am very interested in you". Can we use very in all passive voices?

Comment: @Ahmad, a past participle is a kind of adjective. Some adjectives are gradable- something can have that quality in varying degrees. Some participles are gradable.Broken is both a participle and and an adjective: it is not gradable, so you cannot say **very** broken.

Comment: Note that in informal speech, we do treat _broken_ as gradable sometimes.  See the song 'so broken' by Björk.  Also in software development, a certain product may be referred to as very broken, extremely broken, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *[interest](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/interest_2)* means:

> to make someone want to pay attention to something and find out more about it:
>
> Here's an article which might **interest you**.

or

> to try to persuade someone to buy, do, or eat something
>
> ***interest  somebody in something***
>
> The salesman tried **to interest me in** the higher-priced model.

Then, your first usage of the verb **interest** has no meaning, unless as a clause like:

> I am one of the students you have interested in reading.

It means **You have interested me in reading**.

---

But the second **interested** which is very common and comes with "**in**" preposition is an **adjective** (past participle).

> You have always been interested in reading.
>
> You are very interested in reading.

Answer (score 0):

To talk about a wish to do something,we use "interested" with an _ing form.     I am interested in working in India.